# Using Bokeh Slider Widget by Changing DataFrame to ColumnDataSource Data

Tags: python, bokeh

Using the Elements periodic table sample data from Bokeh, I'm trying to create a slider widget to filter the glyphs by size (using the "van der waals radius" column). I have different glyph sets for gas, liquid, and solid, with different colors corresponding to each.

I'm having trouble understanding how to use the slider with the DataFrame data, since I have to put it into ColumnDataSource. To make matters more complicated, there are 3 sets of glyphs (gas, liquid, and solid), so I'm not sure if this requires a slider for each, or if there is a way to combine (would be ideal).

When I run the current code below, I get the following error:

> error handling message Message 'PATCH-DOC' (revision 1): ValueError('operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (160,) (40,) ',)

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.sampledata.periodic_table import elements
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Range1d
from bokeh.models.annotations import Span, Label
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider

elements.dropna(inplace=True)

colormap={"gas":"yellow","liquid":"orange","solid":"red"}
elements["color"]=[colormap[x] for x in elements["standard state"]]
elements["size"]= elements["van der Waals radius"]/10

gas=ColumnDataSource(elements[elements["standard state"]=="gas"])
solid=ColumnDataSource(elements[elements["standard state"]=="solid"])
liquid=ColumnDataSource(elements[elements["standard state"]=="liquid"])

gas1=ColumnDataSource(elements[elements["standard state"]=="gas"])
solid1=ColumnDataSource(elements[elements["standard state"]=="solid"])
liquid1=ColumnDataSource(elements[elements["standard state"]=="liquid"])

f=figure()

f.xaxis.axis_label="Atomic Radius"
f.yaxis.axis_label="Boiling Point"

f.circle(x="atomic radius",y="boiling point", size='size',
         fill_alpha=0.2, color='color', legend="Gas", source=gas)
f.circle(x="atomic radius",y="boiling point", size='size',
         fill_alpha=0.2, color='color', legend="Liquid", source=liquid)
f.circle(x="atomic radius",y="boiling point", size='size',
         fill_alpha=0.2, color='color', legend="Solid", source=solid)

def filter_size(attr, old, new):
    N = slider.value
    new1 = ColumnDataSource(elements.loc[(elements[elements["standard state"]=="gas"]) & (elements["van der Waals radius"] >= N)])
    new2 = ColumnDataSource(elements.loc[(elements[elements["standard state"]=="solid"]) & (elements["van der Waals radius"] >= N)])
    new3 = ColumnDataSource(elements.loc[(elements[elements["standard state"]=="liquid"]) & (elements["van der Waals radius"] >= N)])
    gas1.data = new1.data
    solid1.data = new2.data
    liquid1.data = new3.data
    print(slider.value)

slider=Slider(start=min(elements["van der Waals radius"]-1),end=max(elements["van der Waals radius"])+1,value=10,step=1.0,title="Van der Waals Radius: ")
slider.on_change("value",filter_size)

lay_out=layout([slider])

curdoc().add_root(f)

curdoc().add_root(lay_out)
```

*You can import the sample data to see what it looks like:

```
from bokeh.sampledata.periodic_table import elements
```